# IndentationError: expected an indented block error in python when use "def"

Tags: python, function

I'm an in python. I'm trying to learn using functions. My code block and error are below. Could you help me please How can I use "def" word to describe a function. How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

---

```
 File "C:/Users/tCLARABUL/PycharmProjects/test/WScall.py", line 8
    url == "http://zzzz:80/xxx/yyy?WSDL"
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

---

```
import requests

def inka(ntfid):

url = "http://zzzz:80/xxx/yyy?WSDL"

headers = yyy

body = "xxx""

response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)

return response.text

print(inka(122727))
```

Comment: Python uses indentation for control-flow - and for scopes. Please indent your code as you have it in your IDE. Make sure you are consistent - either use tabs or spaces and if spaces use the same amount (by custom: 4) for scoping

Comment: @Patrick Artner I did not fix the indentation only added code formatting

Comment: @mrangry777 My bad, I seem to have misjugded the before/after view then. sorry-

Comment: @Levent Arabul If an answer resolved your issue mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python is tab sensitive so after def the code needs to be with tab
try this:

```
import requests

def inka(ntfid):
    url = "http://zzzz:80/xxx/yyy?WSDL"
    headers = yyy
    body = "xxx""
    response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)

    return response.text

print(inka(122727))
```

Comment: "Needs to be with tab" is misleading and technically wrong. Spaces can be used as well and are actually the [recommended](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) choice.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It is fixed.

Comment: FlyingTeller - detail mate :D code's copied... tabs added with spaces, anyone will tell you that technically python is tabs sensitive so you can argue for spaces if you want, but thats the official definition :)

Answer (score 2):

To be precise in python indentation mark the scope of variables etc. So you need an indent for functions

```
def inka(ntfid):
    url = "http://zzzz:80/xxx/yyy?WSDL"
    headers = yyy
    body = "xxx""
    response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)

    return response.text
```

The same applies to `if else` statements:

```
if:
   pass
else:
   pass
```

And classes, methods, `try except` block etc. Also be sure to commit to one form of indents spaces or tabs mixing them gives odd errors.